# different bar text for different groups in plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have the following table:

[image]

I know how to create a grouped bar chart, with single text column:

```
fig = px.bar(data_frame = df.toPandas(),
x = 'x',
y = ['y1','y2'],
barmode = 'group',
text='y1_labels')
fig.show()
```

which generates:
[image]

as you can see, the bars of 'y2' also gets the labels of 'y1_labels' - while I would like them to have their own labels from 'y2_labels'.

how can this be achived?

Comment: Since your labels are truly the values formatted differently, you need the argument `text_auto`, not `text`. To get percentages, use `text_auto = '0%'`; I'm pretty sure that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that - but I would still wish an answer to the original question, in case the labels are not the values formatted differently